# Calculate Value at Risk for a futures contract or option position

Tags: options, futures, value-at-risk

How could we calculate VaR for a futures contract or a option position? I know that a VaR is calculated by the return multiply the investment amount, but how could we calculate the investment amount of a future contract or options? Espeically for short position, the above formula become more confused.

Anyone give a hint when applying VaR to Futures contract and Options, thanks!

Comment: [Helpful book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0071464956)

Comment: Thanks! It helps, but still need more references for options and more example for futures.